# how to click type="button" via python mechanize

Tags: python, mechanize

I have an html button:

```
<button align="center" id="btnApply" width = "100" type="button" value="Apply" style="width:100px" onClick='Submit(1,getElement("btnApply"));'>
```

I tried to click this button with this code

```
br.submit(label='Apply',id='btnApply')
```

but I got this error:

```
no control matching kind 'clickable', id 'btnApply', label 'Apply'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since that button has a JavaScript event attached, `mechanize` cannot really help you here. It is mostly a HTML parser with some additional support for links and filling out forms. But it cannot interpret JavaScript and generally doesn’t really *run* anything on that website.

If you’re looking for something that can completely emulate the browser’s behavior on a website with JavaScript support, you should look into a headless browser. This is basically a browser without the “visual” part. For example, you could use [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) and run your tests using [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/).

Otherwise, if you’re not looking into testing, but just want that one request to go through, you should investigate that website closely and figure out what the `Submit(1,getElement("btnApply"))` code does. Then emulate that and send the request directly to the server—you don’t even need `mechanize` then but can likely just do normal HTTP requests (for example using urllib in the standard library or [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)).